# Menu Responsive

Tags: menus

How do i make my menu bar responsive? The menu doesn't change together with the header when I crop my window to mobile size, leaving an empty space between header image and menu bar or showing menu two times repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Your nav menu bar responcive while can user **bootstrap framework**.

> This like code insert in **function.php**

[Bootstrap responcive nav menu wordpress](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)

// This code insert in **header.php**

```
<div class="container"> 
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">  
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#medi-temp-navbar-collapse"> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="medi-temp-navbar-collapse">    
        <?php
            if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) {
                wp_nav_menu( array( 
                    'theme_location' => 'primary',
                      'container'=>false,
                      'walker'=>new wp_bootstrap_navwalker(),
                      'menu_class'=>'nav navbar-nav',
                    ) 
                );
            }
        ?>                      
    </div>
   </nav><!-- nav -->
</div><!-- container -->
```

[wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress)[bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap)[walker-nav-menu](/questions/tagged/walker-nav-menu)